# How to get the ember data store instance from within the new router object?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm porting an existing app to the new router api and can't find an example where someone reaches into the router and grabs the apps store to query for data.

Here is my old router

```
CodeCamp.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  root: Ember.Route.extend({
    index: Ember.Route.extend({
      route: '/',
      connectOutlets: function(router, context) {
        router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('sessions', router.get('store').findAll(CodeCamp.Session));
      }
    })
  })
});
```

Here is the start to my new router but the "router.get('store')" doesn't like the word router and the keyword "this" also returns undefined.

```
CodeCamp.Router.map(function(match) {
      match("/").to("sessions");
});

CodeCamp.SessionsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplates: function() {
        this.render('sessions');
    },                                                                                                             
    setupControllers: function() {
        this.set('controller.content', this.get('store').findAll(CodeCamp.Session));
    }
});
```

**Update**

I can get it to work with the following (it just seems ugly and I'd prefer another way)

```
setupControllers: function() {
  this.set('controller.content', CodeCamp.Session.all().get('store').findAll(CodeCamp.Session));
}
```

Comment: What about simply `CodeCamp.Session.find()` ? I'm not aware of bleeding edge ember-data, but this should work, shouldn't it ?

Comment: excellent -for some odd reason I didn't try this initially even though @tomdale had it in the v2 gist like this. I just assumed my ember-data adapter wouldn't work with this but clearly I was wrong (thanks @sly7_7) -now if you could just add this as a legit answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `CodeCamp.Session.find()` ;)

Comment: I deselected your answer because I found that I still need a way to get at the store to commit changes globally (and the controller to router to store approach I used in ember 1.0 pre isn't working -even though your .find() does help me do a select.) How can I get the app wide store instance to commit all dirty changes?

Comment: CodeCamp.Session.all().get('store').commit(); does work to do the commit - again I just hope to find a cleaner way if possible ?

Comment: hum, controller.get('store').commit() should work, does'nt it ?

Comment: haha you are the man -looks like this.get('store').commit() works from within my controller :)